# How to drop NA rows in a column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader

I have a data frame with about 5 N/A values and I'm trying to get rid of them based on what pandas documentation says:

```
df.dropna(subset=['new_tests'], how='any')
```

which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You need to reassign `df = df.dropna(subset=['new_tests'], how='any')`.

Comment: It's not `inplace`. Hence,you need to re-assign. Or `df.dropna(subset=['new_tests'], how='any', inplace=True)`

Comment: just simply try `df.dropna(subset = ['new_test'])`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, not sure in pandas changed this but you don't need to pass `how='any'`
so `df.dropna(subset=['new_tests'])` works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing

```
df=df.dropna(subset=['new_tests'])
```

as by default the value of how is 'any'.